# How to profile spring-boot application memory consumption?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring-boot app that I suspect might have a memory leak. Over time the memory consumption seems to increase, taking like 500M of memory until I restart the application. After a fresh restart it takes something like 150M. The spring-boot app should be a pretty stateless rest app, and there shouldn't be any objects left around after request is completed. I would wish the garbage collector would take care of this.

Currently on production the spring-boot app seems to use 343M of memory (RSS). I got the heapdump of the application and analysed it. According to the analysis the heapdump is only 31M of size. So where does the missing 300M lie in? How is the heapdump correlated with the actual memory the application is using? And how could I profile the memory consumption past the heapdump? If the memory used is not in the heap, then where is it? How to discover what is consuming the memory of the spring-boot application?

Comment: Eclipse MAT can do this. And many more: https://dzone.com/articles/top-9-free-java-process-monitoring-tools-amp-how-t

Comment: I think it only analyses the heap. And the heap seems to not take that much memory. So I wonder if I would benefit from heap analysis at all

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us how and where / in which tool you see the memory consumption. Perhaps you are trying to solve a problem that isn't there

Comment: I used visualvm to analyse the heapdump file. Also basic linux tools to see the memory consumption

Comment: Use Java tools, not OS tools because they give a false view. You are searching for a memory leak that doesn't exist. See what Java uses the process memory for:https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/11/memory-footprint-of-the-jvm

Comment: I knew I had that link somewhere ... You also might want to read the part about kernel tools here: https://spring.io/blog/2015/12/10/spring-boot-memory-performance

Comment: Now the app has increased it's memory consumption again to 50% of all memory. Can't release new version anymore because it crashes because not enough memory =/. I think it's the off-heap memory that is being increased, since the heap size stays the same

Comment: Threads with their stacks are not stored on the heap, so if there is heavy threading that might be the issue. 
Still it would it be interesting to see the hprof file if you could share it. Btw, which JDK are you using?

Answer (score 6):

We can view how much of memory consumption in spring boot app, in this way.

1. Create spring boot app as `.jar` file and execute it using `java -jar springboot-example.jar`
2. Now open the CMD and type **`jconsole`** and hit enter.

   **Note** :- before opening the jconsole you need to run `.jar` file
3. Now you can see a window like below and it will appear application that previously ran in **Local Process** section.
   [image: jcosole]
4. Select springboot-example.jar and click below **connect** button.
5. After it will show the below prompt and give **Insecure connection** option.
   [image: prompt]
6. Finally you can see Below OverView (Heap Memory, Threads...).
   [image: overview]

Answer (score 5):

Besides heap, you have thread stacks, meta space, JIT code cache, native shared libraries and the off-heap store (direct allocations).

I would start with thread stacks: how many threads does your application spawn at peak? Each thread is likely to allocate 1MB for its stack by default, depending on Java version, platform, etc. With (say) 300 active threads (idle or not), you'll allocate 300MB of stack memory.

Consider making all your thread pools fixed-size (or at least provide reasonable upper bounds). Even if this proves not to be root cause for what you observed, it makes the app behaviour more deterministic and will help you better isolate the problem.

Comment: To find out the default stack size in kilobytes for your jvm (in case you're not overwriting that for your app with `-Xss`), run `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep ThreadStackSize`. To check the live threads, use `jstack`.

Comment: Default size was 1024 kb I think. Tried running jstack. Had to introduce the -F flag for it. The result with that was:JVM version is 25.282-b08
Deadlock Detection:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deduce type of thread from address 0x00007f9f1c034800 (expected type JavaThread, CompilerThread, ServiceThread, JvmtiAgentThread, or SurrogateLockerThread)

Comment: It's likely that the error message is misleading. You need to run `jstack` as the owner of that process, running as a different user may result in such atrocities sometimes.

Comment: True, got it working now. Somewhat long response. In the end there's line: 'JNI global references: 2108"

Comment: `jstack ${pid} | grep 'java.lang.Thread.State' | wc -l`

Comment: I got the thread count by issuing: ps -o thcount. Count was 31. So 31M total

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229864/discussion-between-ville-miekk-oja-and-costi-ciudatu).

Answer (score 5):

> So where does the missing 300M lie in?

A lot of research has gone into this, especially in trying to tune the parameters that control the non-heap. One result of this research is the [memory calculator](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-memory-calculator) ([binary](https://repo.spring.io/list/release/org/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-memory-calculator/)).

You see, in Docker environments with a hard limit on the available amount of memory, the JVM will crash when it tries to allocate more memory than is available. Even with all the research, the `memory calculator` still has a slack-option called "head-room" - usually set to 5 to 10% of total available memory in case the JVM decides to grab some more memory anyway (e.g. during intensive garbage collection).

Apart from "head-room", the `memory calculator` needs 4 additional input-parameters to calculate the Java options that control memory usage.

- `total-memory` - a minimum of 384 MB for Spring Boot application, start with 512 MB.
- `loaded-class-count` - for latest Spring Boot application about 19 000. This seems to grow with each Spring version. Note that this is a maximum: setting a too low value will result in all kinds of weird behavior (sometimes an "OutOfMemory: non-heap" exception is thrown, but not always).
- `thread-count` - 40 for a "normal usage" Spring Boot web-application.
- `jvm-options` - see the two parameters below.

The "Algorithm" section mentions additional parameters that can be tuned, of which I found two worth the effort to investigate per application and specify:

- `-Xss` set to 256kb. Unless your application has really deep stacks (recursion), going from 1 MB to 256kb per thread saves a lot of memory.
- `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize` set to 64MB. Peak "CodeCache" usage is often during application startup, going from 192 MB to 64 MB saves a lot of memory which can be used as heap. Applications that have a lot of active code during runtime (e.g. a web-application with a lot of endpoints) may need more "CodeCache". If "CodeCache" is too low, your application will use a lot of CPU without doing much (this can also manifest during startup: if "CodeCache" is too low, your application can take a very long time to startup). "CodeCache" is reported by the JVM as a non-heap memory region, it should not be hard to measure.

The output of the `memory calculator` is a bunch of Java options that all have an effect on what memory the JVM uses. If you really want to know where "the missing 300M" is, study and research each of these options in addition to the "Java Buildpack Memory Calculator v3" [rationale](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vlXBiwRIjwiVcbvUGYMrxx2Aw1RVAtxq3iuZ3UK2vXA/edit?usp=sharing).

```
# Memory calculator 4.2.0

$ ./java-buildpack-memory-calculator --total-memory 512M --loaded-class-count 19000 --thread-count 40 --head-room 5 --jvm-options "-Xss256k -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64M"

-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=121289K -Xmx290768K

# Combined JVM options to keep your total application memory usage under 512 MB:

-Xss256k -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=121289K -Xmx290768K
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "JProfiler" https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html
remotely or locally to monitor running java app memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

You can using "yourkit" with IntelliJ  if you are using that as your IDE to troubleshoot memory related issues for your spring boot app. I have used this before and it provides better insight to applications.

https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/idea.jsp

Answer (score 2):

Interesting article about memory profiling: https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers